# How to pass path in double quotes to sql file

Tags: batch-file, sqlplus

I want to pass the current batch file path to sql file which will be called by sqlplus and spool the result into that path. My code is below. Its failing at spool line as the path is not passed with double quotes. Can you please help me

start sqlplus %DBUName%/%DBPwd%@%GISName% "@%~dp0SQL\SetUp\SETUP.sql" "%~dp0Config\SETUP.ok"

In the set up sql, I have given the below line

SPOOL &1

Comment: Is 'sqlplus' an exe or batch file?

Answer (score 2):

Quick guess:

```
start "" sqlplus....
```

---

Well now! There was an interesting exercise.

```
start "" sqlplus %DBUName%/%DBPwd%@%GISName% "@%~dp0SQL\SetUp\SETUP.sql" "%~dp0Config\SETUP.ok"
```

Is a standard solution to the "quoted arguments" problem with `start`. The first `"quoted string"` is assigned as the window's title - that is what the normal complaint is. Inserting the apparently-redundant empty string provides no title to the window - it's actually the simplest form of "this is the window title I want" - and a lot easier to type.

I didn't have time to test this in any way, which is why I suggested it as a guess. I tried with a batch file called `sqlplus.bat` which simply displayed its arguments:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal
echo @~nx0 received ==^>%*^<==
pause
exit
```

But this seemed to deliver all of the arguments as expected.

So since `sqlplus` is an executable, I thought I'd install it and try. Er - 33Mb min, and all the legalese sign-on and passwords and yet another account I'm only ever going to use once...Na.

So I built my own `sqlplus.exe` in Delphi - simply evaluating the command-line arguments. Thirty seconds' work.

Problem was that there was no way I could get the executable to show quotes in the parameters using the function that purports to return arguments by position. So **THAT** I had to investigate. I discovered a function to return the entire command-line as supplied - and there were the quotes, large as life.

Turns out there's a Delphi bug where `paramstr(x)` removes enclosing quotes from the value returned for argument x. Reported that to EMBT.

And re-tested, using the executable I'd constructed - displaying the command-line itself (`cmdline` if you're interested) and - well, bad news in the context of this problem - my tests show that

```
start sqlplus %DBUName%/%DBPwd%@%GISName% "@%~dp0SQL\SetUp\SETUP.sql" "%~dp0Config\SETUP.ok"
```

and

```
start "" sqlplus %DBUName%/%DBPwd%@%GISName% "@%~dp0SQL\SetUp\SETUP.sql" "%~dp0Config\SETUP.ok"
```

both deliver the same command-line - quotes included as written.

So - it would appear that the problem is with `sqlplus` or the instruction(s) `sqlplus` executes. The quoted strings appear to be delivered to the executable just fine.

Suppose OP executes

sqlplus %DBUName%/%DBPwd%@%GISName% "@%~dp0SQL\SetUp\SETUP.sql" "%~dp0Config\SETUP.ok"

(after substituting the appropriate parameters) - does this show the quotes as expected? (that question is really an `SQLPLUS` question and off-topic for this tag. AND I've no idea about `sqlplus`.

---

Additional (Well, really a comment, but it doesn't fit the comment system too well...) I believe we're running into language or terminalogical problems...

Does

sqlplus %DBUName%/%DBPwd%@%GISName% "@%~dp0SQL\SetUp\SETUP.sql" "%~dp0Config\SETUP.ok"

when executed with exactly that syntax (but with `%dbuName%`, etc. substituted with the actual name) operate correctly when executed directly from the command prompt?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: No.. I want to pass the path "%~dp0Config\SETUP.ok" in double quotes. When i use the above code, then in sql file it looks like SPOOL Z:\Test folder\test folder 1\SETUP.ok but i want the code should pass the value like SPOOL "Z:\Test folder\test folder 1\SETUP.ok"

Comment: @RaulRene It lloks odd, but I suppose it's really the answer, as `start` has special rules with quotes. And the first quotes are handled here as the window title

Comment: @jeb: The first quote you mean "@%~dp0SQL\SetUp\SETUP.sql"?? This is the path where my sql placed

Comment: @RaulRene : since you showed an interest - I'm not sure you'd get notifiations of updates...

Comment: My initial comment was a review because the answer was shallow and sounded like a guess. I'm glad it worked out and that it developed into such an elaborated response. +1

Comment: @Magoo: Either way ie substituting the original path or ~dp0config\SETUP.ok, it is not working since both values are passed without double quotes when to passed to sqlplus. It is working only if i give the original path with double quotes in the SETUP.sql file

Comment: All, Thanks for your time. I will wait for some better solutions for my issue. Until then my temporary solution would be create the setup.ok flag file in users local C: so that the next sqlplus command will check the same and invoke

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, what you need. Do you need *more* quotes or *no* quotes. Whatsoever- 
you can have as many quotes as you want. I do not have `sqlplus`, but it's not so important. I can show you this with 'calc.exe`:

[image]

And I think, this is not a cmd/Batch issue. It belongs to your `sqlplus`.

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
title Test of Quotes
set dbuname=dbuname
set DBPwd=DBPwd
set gisname=gisname

start calc %dbuname%/%DBPwd%@%gisname% @%~dp0SQL\SetUp\SETUP.sql %~dp0Config\SETUP.ok
start calc %dbuname%/%DBPwd%@%gisname% @%~dp0SQL\SetUp\SETUP.sql "%~dp0Config\SETUP.ok"
start calc %dbuname%/%DBPwd%@%gisname% "@%~dp0SQL\SetUp\SETUP.sql" %~dp0Config\SETUP.ok
start calc %dbuname%/%DBPwd%@%gisname% "@%~dp0SQL\SetUp\SETUP.sql" "%~dp0Config\SETUP.ok"
start calc %dbuname%/%DBPwd%@%gisname% "@%~dp0SQL\SetUp\SETUP.sql" ""%~dp0Config\SETUP.ok""
start calc %dbuname%/%DBPwd%@%gisname% ""@%~dp0SQL\SetUp\SETUP.sql"" ""%~dp0Config\SETUP.ok""
start calc %dbuname%/%DBPwd%@%gisname% """@%~dp0SQL\SetUp\SETUP.sql""" ""%~dp0Config\SETUP.ok""
start calc %dbuname%/%DBPwd%@%gisname% """@%~dp0SQL\SetUp\SETUP.sql""" """%~dp0Config\SETUP.ok"""

ping -n 3 localhost > nul

wmic process where name='calc.exe' get commandline
```

Comment: The issue not in batch file but sqlplus having an issue that truncates double quotes. When batch file passes parameter with double quotes, sqlplus ignores that double quotes. Hence if u help me how to spool a file to the path which am passing through batch file then that would be great help

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean with `. Hence if u help  how to spool a file to the path which am passing through batch file`.

Comment: I mean if you help on how to extract a result of sql query that run via sql query and stores in a path where I am passing as parameters then that would help me